# Why a filter defined in guice does not listen on /*?

Tags: guice, guice-servlet, guice-3

My DI framework is Guice. I also use sitebricks. Perhaps I am fascinated by how simple these two APIs are. However I want to bind a filter, using guice, to listen to /* however the filter only listens on / ? Why is that?

```
public class CoreModule extends ServletModule {


    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
                                filter("/*").through(Guard.class);
                                install(new SsoModule());
                                install(new PersistenceModule());
                   } 

            }
```

When I call `localhost:8080/` the filter is executed but when I call `localhost:8080/index` the filter is not executed! Why is that?

Comment: What's your `web.xml`? Definitely, it should work. I think you have registered another filter which will response before your `Guard` filter or even before `Guice` filter.

Comment: yes Milan is correct. Share web.xml also If there are any other filter that was registered in web.xml prior to Guard then that filter will be called.